# Eclipse Installation Errors

Tags: java, eclipse, installation

I have been trying to install Eclipse on my Windows 10 Dell PC.
Here's how my `eclipse.ini` file looks like originally:-

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.4.0.v20161219-1356.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.551.v20171108-1834
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
-showsplash
org.eclipse.epp.package.common
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/eclipse-workspace
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
```

I have been trying to do the following:-

Changed version from 1.8 to 1.7 as I have installed Java 1.7

Added this before `-vmargs`

```
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\bin\javaw.exe
```

Also changing `-Xmx1024m` to `-Xmx512m`

But still some or the other error occurs and I am totally clueless about what is happening

I get errors like
`Cannot create Java Virtual Machine`

or

`An error has occurred. See log \some\path in configuration folder` whose content I am unable to understand

I **don't** have any workspace where I can delete .metadata/.plugins *some file path to something call .snap* where I can delete that

Also, tried -clean command, that doesn't works too.

Comment: It seems like your eclipse version requires Java 8 (all of the more recent ones do), judging also by the `-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8`. You could try installing a newer version of Java. If you use the eclipse installer, it should also let you select which VM you want to use and it also tells you what the minimum required version is.

Comment: So, how do I uninstall the earlier Java version and install a new one?

Comment: try adding this lines --launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m 
-Xms40m

Comment: Tried those already, it doesn't helps

Comment: Just download a newer JDK and install it, you don't need to remove the old one.

Comment: Download a JDK for Windows x64 e. g. here: [Java 8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) or [Java 10](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk10-downloads-4416644.html)

Answer (score 0):

I would start with cleaning your system, that means uninstall Java completely with all of its versions. Either that, or try to upload that log you cannot understand, maybe some of us will and it will shine a light on your situation.